# pretrained densenet/vgg16/resnet50 + gp does not train on cifar10 data

Tags: gpflow

I'm trying to train a hybrid model with GP on top of pre-trained CNN (Densenet, VGG and Resnet) with CIFAR10 data, mimic the ex2 function in the gpflow document. But the testing result is always between 0.1~0.2, which generally means random guess (Wilson+2016 paper shows hybrid model for CIFAR10 data should get accuracy of 0.7). Could anyone give me a hint of what could be wrong?

I've tried same code with simpler cnn models (2 conv layer or 4 conv layer) and both have reasonable results. I've tried to use different Keras applications: Densenet121, VGG16, ResNet50, neither works. I've tried to freeze the weights in the pre-trained models still not working.

```py
def cnn_dn(output_dim):
    base_model = DenseNet121(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(32,32,3))
    bout = base_model.output
    fcl = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(bout)
    #for layer in base_model.layers:
    #    layer.trainable = False
    output=Dense(output_dim, activation='relu')(fcl)
    md=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
    return md

#add gp on top, reference:ex2() function in
#https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/GPflow/GPflow/blob/develop/doc/source/notebooks/tailor/gp_nn.ipynb
#needs to slightly change build graph part because keras variable #sharing is not the same as tensorflow
#......

## build graph
with tf.variable_scope('cnn'):
    md=cnn_dn(gp_dim)
    f_X = tf.cast(md(X), dtype=float_type)
    f_Xtest = tf.cast(md(Xtest), dtype=float_type)

#......

    ## predict

res=np.argmax(sess.run(my, feed_dict={Xtest:xts}),1).reshape(yts.shape)
correct = res == yts.astype(int)
print(np.average(correct.astype(float)))
```

Comment: Could you turn this into a minimal working (well, failing, but runnable!) example? Being able to simply copy & paste a script to reproduce an issue makes it significantly easier to investigate it for other people!

Answer (score 1):

I finally figure out that the solution is training larger iterations. In the original code, I just use 50 iterations as used in the ex2() function for MNIST data and it is not enough for more complicated network and CIFAR10 data. Adjusting some hyper-parameter (e.g. learning rate and activation function) also helps.